# How to resolve code line from Mbed crash dump on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, crash, arm, elf, mbed

An Mbed code is throwing the crash dump below and I wish to find the line corresponding to the given PC. I'm on Windows though, so the simple "*addr2line*" is not available. I tried *addr2line* with Ubuntu shell on Windows, but it gives ??:?

What is the best tool on **Windows 10** to perform address-to-line resolution from ARM ELF?

```
++ MbedOS Fault Handler ++

FaultType: HardFault

Context:
R0: 0
R1: 2000A0C8
R2: 1
R3: 14
R4: 20007854
R5: 2000A0
R6: 68
R7: 0
R8: 0
R9: 0
R10: 0
R11: 0
R12: 29FC1
SP   : 2000A8B8
LR   : 2C007
PC   : 2000A0C8
xPSR : 0
PSP  : 2000A898
MSP  : 2003FFC0
CPUID: 410FC241
HFSR : 40000000
MMFSR: 0
BFSR : 0
UFSR : 2
DFSR : 0
AFSR : 0
Mode : Thread
Priv : Privileged
Stack: PSP

-- MbedOS Fault Handler --
```

Comment: is this optimized code? there isnt a link between machine code and high level code, can you compare the disassembly to the fault?  you are running code in ram yes?  or is the fault that you tried to branch to ram?

Comment: start with arm-whatever-objdump...

Comment: The code is built in "develop" mode, which is medium-optimized, something between "debug" and "release"... Yes, running in RAM.
How to get the "disassembly"?

Comment: start with arm-whatever-objdump

Comment: mbed .... use decent ide having HF parse plugin. It is 21st century

Answer (score 0):

The crash log parser script in Mbed OS (https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/tree/master/tools/debug_tools/crash_log_parser) takes a crash dump and an ELF file and will actually tell the crash location (plus some helpful tips on what the actual error was).